# Strange `path` data in ArcGIS JSON response

Tags: arcgis-server, json

Our local government runs a MapServer with geo data about the county land, property parcels and such. They provide this data as a bulk download, but some layers are missing. I decided to extract a small piece from around my house to model the relief for home improvement purposes. Grabbed the JSON response from the MapServer and was surprised to see the following:

```json
"geometry":
  {
    "paths":
      [
        [
          [-32788557.0,-4020983.0],[18.0,-18.0],[16.0,-20.0],[14.0,-29.0],[10.0,-5.0][1.0,-2.0],
           3.0,1.0],[2.0,-1.0],[10.0,5.0],[4.0,8.0],[-6.0,9.0],[0.0,4.0]
        ]
      ]
   }
```

This is obviously a small excerpt, but all the `path`s look the same: a coordinate pair with giant values as the first point and then a long series of pairs in low single/double digits. All integer (fraction is always 0).

Any idea what it is and how to convert it to something more understandable? I tried to load it into QGIS and despite that it automatically recognized the format the result is completely messed up. Some giant triangle covering the whole planet :-)

This data is elevation contours if that helps.

GeoJSON is not available there, they don't run servers to support it.

The header:

```json
{
  "displayFieldName": "Type",
  "transform": {
    "originPosition": "upperLeft",
    "scale": [
      0.5971642835591084,
      0.5971642835591084
    ],
    "translate": [
      5975825.080599502,
      2086803.942522511
    ]
  },
  "fieldAliases": {
    "OBJECTID": "OBJECTID",
    "Elevation": "Elevation",
    "Type": "Type",
    "Shape_Length": "Shape_Length"
  },
  "geometryType": "esriGeometryPolyline",
  "spatialReference": {
    "wkid": 102100,
    "latestWkid": 3857
  },
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "OBJECTID",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeOID",
      "alias": "OBJECTID"
    },
    {
      "name": "Elevation",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
      "alias": "Elevation"
    },
    {
      "name": "Type",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
      "alias": "Type",
      "length": 50
    },
    {
      "name": "Shape_Length",
      "type": "esriFieldTypeDouble",
      "alias": "Shape_Length"
    }
  ],
  "features": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "OBJECTID": 352679,
        "Elevation": 917,
        "Type": "Basic",
        "Shape_Length": 8398.660869832049
      },
      "geometry": ...
```

Comment: It seems the first pair are actual projected coordinates and what follows are offsets.

Comment: @TomazicM that was my first thought, but I can't find it documented anywhere. How can I tell if the polyline is in absolute coordinates or in relative ones?

Comment: You must get that info from the source of the data or you have a look at the data and try to guess.